# Como llamar un array de objetos en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando con Angular 7 y tengo un API REST que me devuelve esto:

```
{"Placa":"MIN123","Certificaciones":[{"Archivo":"KIO","fecha":"12-02-2018","Nombre":1},{"Archivo":"KIO","fecha":"12-02-2018","Nombre":1},{"Archivo":"preventiva","fechai":"06-02-2018","fechav":"12-02-2018","Nombre":2},{"Archivo":"preventiva","fechai":"06-02-2019","fechav":"25-03-2019","Nombre":2}],"Lugares":[{"lugar":"inicio","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 99 No.69A 81"},{"lugar":"Fin","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 89 No.69A 81"}],"Inconvenientes":[{"lugar":"Fin","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 89 No.69A 81","Descripcion":"No reporta"}],"id":"5c7c990de5b1660fb032dc8b"}
```

por medio del link: "http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/5c7c990de5b1660fb032dc8b" mi APP de Angular la tengo asi:

**Mi servicio**

```
//data-api.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import {HttpClient,HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable' ;
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { VehiculoInterface } from '../Modelo/vehiculo-interface';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataAPIService {
    vehiculos: Observable<any>;
    vehiculo: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    getVehiculoByID(id: string){
     const url_api = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/${id}';
     this.vehiculo=this.http.get(url_api);
     console.log(this.vehiculo);
     return (this.vehiculo);
    } 
}
```

Segun lo que he leido de interfaces mis interfaces son asi:

**Certificaciones**

```
//vcertificaciones-interface.ts
export interface vcertificacionesInterface{
    Archivo ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    Nombre ?: number;
}
```

**Inconvenientes**

```
//vinconvenientes-interface.ts
export interface vinconvenientesInterface{
    lugar ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    direccion ?: string;
    Descripcion?:string;
}
```

**Lugares**

```
//vlugares-interface.ts
export interface vlugaresInterface{
    lugar ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    direccion ?: string;
}
```

**Vehiculos**

```
//vehiculo-interface.ts
import {vcertificacionesInterface} from "./vcertificaciones-interface";
import {vinconvenientesInterface}from "./vinconvenientes-interface";
import {vlugaresInterface}from "./vlugares-interface";

export interface VehiculoInterface{
    Placa ?: string;
    Estado ?: number;
    Certificaciones ?:vcertificacionesInterface[];
    Inconvenientes ?: vinconvenientesInterface[];
    Lugares ?: vlugaresInterface[];
}
```

y por el momento quiero mostrarlo por consola, pero obiamente lo voy a poner en el HTML.
Entonces implemente mi componente asi:

```
//detalles-vehiculos.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataAPIService } from 'src/app/Servicios/data-api.service';
import { ActivatedRoute,Params } from '@angular/router';
import { VehiculoInterface } from 'src/app/Modelo/vehiculo-interface';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalles-vehiculos',
  templateUrl: './detalles-vehiculos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalles-vehiculos.component.css']
})
export class DetallesVehiculosComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataAPI:DataAPIService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  private vehiculo: VehiculoInterface={
    Placa :'',
    Estado :null,
    Certificaciones:null,
    Inconvenientes:null,
    Lugares:null
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const vehiculoid=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getDetails(vehiculoid);
    console.log(this.vehiculo);
  }

  getDetails(id:string){
    this.dataAPI.getVehiculoByID(id)
      .subscribe(vehiculo => this.vehiculo = vehiculo);
      console.log(this.vehiculo);
  }

}
```

y no he podido me sale este error y la verdad si estoy perdido porque el API REST si funciona y no entiendo

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/$%7Bid%7D 404 (Not Found)
>
> ERROR
>   HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not
>   Found", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/$%7Bid%7D", ok:
>   false, …}

Creo, que lo que tengo mal, es como lo tomo por el componente, fui lo mas descriptivo que pude con mi problema, por favor ayudenme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el error no está en el código que has puesto. Vamos a intentar deducir el problema:

- Un error 404 significa que la URL que estás usando es incorrecta.
- El error que te da es `GET http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/$%7Bid%7D 404 (Not Found)`.
- Esa URL tiene caracteres escapados, decodifiquémosla:

```js
console.log(decodeURI('http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/$%7Bid%7D'));
```

- Por tanto, tenemos que la URL usada es `http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/${id}`.
- Conclusión: En tu service querías usar un *string template* pero en lugar de usar las comillas correspondientes:

  ```
  let url=`http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/${id}`;
  ```

  Has usado las de un string normal:

  ```
  let url='http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/${id}';
  ```

Comment: pero de igual forma, me deja todo vacio {Placa: "", Estado: null, Certificaciones: null, Inconvenientes: null, Lugares: null}
Certificaciones: null , 
Estado: null
Inconvenientes: null
Lugares: null
Placa: ""
__proto__: Object  ayudame por favor @Pablo